# Tor keeps in “searching informations about the relay” when ExitNodes parameter is set in torcc file

Tags: configuration, exit-relays, vidalia, node

I added some lines in my torcc file. At first I added:

```
ExitNodes {fr},{be},{ch},{lu},{mc}
StrictNodes 1
```

When I launch Tor with Vidalia it keeps in the state "searching informations about the relay", so it does not connect.

Then I added:

```
EntryNodes {fr},{be},{ch},{lu},{mc}
StrictNodes 0
```

Even changed the argument `StrictNodes` to `0` for `ExitNodes`, it still does not work. So I tried with adding `FascistFirewall 1` as it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#FirewallPorts) but it changes nothing.

### update: log messages.

```
févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Notification] Tor 0.3.5.7 (git-9beb085c10562a25) running on Windows 7 
with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2p, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma N/A, and Libzstd N/A.

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Notification] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! 
Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Notification] Read configuration file 
"C:\Users\Truc\Documents\Tor\Data\Tor\torrc".

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Avertissement] The ReachableDirAddresses option is 
deprecated, and will most likely be removed in a future version of Tor. It 
has no effect on relays, and has had no effect on clients since 0.2.8. (If 
you think this is a mistake, please let us know!)

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Avertissement] Path for GeoIPFile (<default>) is 
relative and will resolve to C:\Users\Truc\Documents\Tor\<default>. Is 
this what you wanted?

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Avertissement] Path for GeoIPv6File (<default>) is 
relative and will resolve to C:\Users\Truc\Documents\Tor\<default>. Is this 
what you wanted?

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Avertissement] Path for DataDirectory 
(C:/Users/Truc/Documents/Tor/Data/Tor) is relative and will resolve to 
C:\Users\Truc\Documents\Tor\Data\Tor. Is this what you wanted?

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Notification] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Notification] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Notification] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Notification] Opened Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Avertissement] Failed to open GEOIP file 
C:\Users\Truc\AppData\Roaming\tor\geoip.

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Avertissement] We've been configured to use (or 
avoid) nodes in certain countries, and we need GEOIP information to figure 
out which ones they are.

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Avertissement] Failed to open GEOIP file 
C:\Users\Truc\AppData\Roaming\tor\geoip6.

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Avertissement] We've been configured to use (or 
avoid) nodes in certain countries, and we need GEOIP information to figure 
out which ones they are.

févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Notification] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting

févr. 24 14:39:02.020 [Avertissement] Your configuration excludes 100% of 
all possible guards. That's likely to make you stand out from the rest of 
the world.

févr. 24 14:39:02.020 [Notification] Starting with guard context 
"restricted"

févr. 24 14:39:02.020 [Notification] New control connection opened from 
127.0.0.1.

févr. 24 15:50:00.216 [Notification] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to 
directory server

févr. 24 15:50:00.351 [Notification] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake 
with directory server

févr. 24 15:50:00.351 [Notification] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay 
descriptors

 févr. 24 15:50:04.671 [Notification] I learned some more directory 
 information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more 
 microdescriptors: we have 6427/6503, and can only build 0% of likely paths. 
 (We have 0% of guards bw, 99% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw = 0% of 
 path bw.)

 févr. 24 15:50:05.336 [Notification] Bootstrapped 50%: Loading relay 
 descriptors

 févr. 24 17:14:04.759 [Notification] I learned some more directory 
 information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more 
 microdescriptors: we have 6478/6522, and can only build 0% of likely paths. 
(We have 0% of guards bw, 99% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw = 0% of path 
bw.)

févr. 24 18:28:01.399 [Avertissement] Tried connecting to router at 
51.254.147.57:443, but RSA + ed25519 identity keys were not as expected: 
wanted EB80A8D52F07238B576C42CEAB98ADD084EE075E + no ed25519 key but got 
D15AFF44BE641368B958A32FB6B071AC2136B8B1 + 
G/N2baMRctZ7vNhZRGxZ1aqwpU04UBVC8d3iHVeQxa4.

févr. 24 18:29:05.424 [Notification] I learned some more directory 
information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more 
microdescriptors: we have 6443/6547, and can only build 0% of likely paths. 
(We have 0% of guards bw, 99% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw = 0% of path 
bw.)

févr. 24 19:50:05.456 [Notification] I learned some more directory 
information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more 
microdescriptors: we have 6494/6558, and can only build 0% of likely paths. 
(We have 0% of guards bw, 99% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw = 0% of path 
bw.)

févr. 24 20:38:59.390 [Notification] Heartbeat: Tor's uptime is 6:00 hours, 
with 0 circuits open. I've sent 56 kB and received 401 kB.

févr. 24 20:38:59.390 [Notification] Average packaged cell fullness: 
73.876%. 
TLS write overhead: 13%

févr. 24 21:33:06.007 [Notification] I learned some more directory 
information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more 
microdescriptors: we have 6471/6581, and can only build 0% of likely paths. 
(We have 0% of guards bw, 99% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw = 0% of path 
bw.)
```

Notes: As I told I use Vidalia 0.2.21, Tor 0.3.4.8 and Polipo proxy configured to run with Tor in Vidalia. Besides, when I erase these added lines it manages to connect with Tor.
Besides file `GeoIPFile` and `GeoIPv6File` were added with the new version of Tor, and the previous version had the problem anyway.

Comment: Have you tried with the latest stable (0.3.5.8)?

Comment: @colbycdev honestly no. But I searched how to update it with a command like it is done in python `pip install --upgrade module`, but I did not find an equivalent. I think will have to reinstall with a new version.

Comment: @colbycdev now I've download it is even worse, it keeps on "starting" in Vidalia.

Comment: I think Vidalia is not supported anymore-hace you tried with pure Tor, and just editing the Torrc?

Comment: @colbycdev I don't know what you call pure Tor, and I guess this is kinda difficult to install, but I have used expert bundle and have extracted contents in right folders and sure edited Torrc with it.

Comment: I mean download Tor from torproject.org, or on Linux added the repos and apt install Tor. If that's not how you got it, it's some sort of fork

Comment: @colbycdev I download from [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) as I said Expert Bundle I am on Windows 7, and I think you are talking about Source Code section of the page. I gonna update with log messages I received, hoping it will clarify the issue.

Comment: no, i just meant the prebundled software

Comment: please do upload logs

Comment: @colbycdev I never downloaded anything else, and it was enough to run Tor by Vidalia, until I added the parameters of nodes.

Comment: hmm. As I said, I believe Vidalia us not official supported. I would also check to ensure that your values are valid, eg fr instead of {fr} and similar. I believe, though, that what you want can be accessed through the GUI, although I've never used Vidalia

Comment: @colbycdev okay. Do you know a good tutorial to install as you say, I mean understandable for non experts like me? Personally I did not find.

Comment: just install from the download link on torproject.org

Answer (score 0):

Tor needs information about the location of those relays. It uses a so-called GeoIP file. Usually this comes with your Tor client. You can also download it from [here](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/config/geoip).

When you look at your log message, there is one line:

```
févr. 24 14:38:56.904 [Avertissement] Failed to open GEOIP file C:\Users\Truc\AppData\Roaming\tor\geoip.
```

This means Tor was not able to find that find. So Tor doesn't which nodes are located in the countries. Thatswhy you find this line in the log:

> Your configuration excludes 100% of 
>   all possible guards. That's likely to make you stand out from the rest of 
>   the world.

So one way to solve it would be to download the GeoIP file and set the option `GeoIPFile`:

```
GeoIPFile C:\Users\Truc\path\to\the\file
```

When you restart Tor it should connect to the network.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu, you can install package with geoip addresses:

```
sudo apt-get install tor-geoipdb
```